# confirmation_url devise not full path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise-confirmable

i try to send email with devise confirmation, but when email have send... url for activation account not have full path

my link_to devise

```
<%= link_to 'Confirm my account', confirmation_url(@user, :confirmation_token => @user.confirmation_token, :host => PATH_URL) %>
```

and i get link like this :

```
http://localhost:3000/users/confirmation
```

not get full path like this

```
http://localhost:3000/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=wtng27FeiWooMGHSEL57
```

Answer (score -1):

Recently devise has changed how the token needs to be referenced, so now the string would be:

```
 <%= link_to 'Confirm my account', confirmation_url(@user, :confirmation_token => @token, :host => PATH_URL) %>
```

This should work.